# Excel VBA XMLHTTP Deleting File

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

I'm really struggling to use XMLHTTP to delete a CSV file. Here is the code I am using;

```
Private Sub delAPIFile()

    Dim Req As New XMLHTTP60
    Req.Open "DELETE", "https://api.*****/csv?api_token=*****", False
    Req.send

    MsgBox (Req.responseText)


 End Sub
```

Many thanks
Mike

Comment: Depends on whether the server fully supports HTTP DELETE method. [HTTP DELETE](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7): "The client cannot be guaranteed that the operation has been carried out, even if the status code returned from the origin server indicates that the action has been completed successfully."

Comment: Hi Axel, yes it does support HTTP Delete. Here is the documentation for the DELETE function on JSON;    // Execute DELETE request to https://api.******/api/v1/scraping-job/<SCRAPING JOB ID>?api_token=<YOUR API TOKEN>

// response
{
 "success": true,
 "data": "ok"
}

Comment: So everyone who knows the URI and the <SCRAPING JOB ID> and the <YOUR API TOKEN> is able to deleting resources from the server? This I cannot believe. Or is there a session involved? Maybe using a session cookie? Please reread the API documentation since we cannot because you have not told us what API is used.

Comment: Yes it is. No need to seem so incredulous. I will give you 2,000,000,001 chances to guess the Scraping ID and the token :-)

Comment: I would say, having security relevant data into the URI is a bad idea (dangerous: sending links with that URIs, having browser history with that URIs, ...). But however, if there is not a session cookie involved, it should work though. What is the result of  `MsgBox Req.responseText`? Or where and how does it fails exactly?